# Stack OverFlow in Plain Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using simple windows.open function to open up a popup window. While teh same is working fine in another page.

Basically there is a user control and that user control has simple table. In there I am using a link button where ONClientClick I am using windows.open('some.aspx'). But it is giving error like Stack OverFlow at line No.

I am unable to get the basic meaning if this thing, why this error can generate and what it signifies?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the batteries in my crystal ball aren't working, I'll try to fix it soon. Could you post the code so we can analyze it?

Comment: You either have an infinite loop or are using too much memory for some complex calculation. Since it is a simple `onclick` event, i would say the #1. Code please.

Comment: I don't think your exception is in Javascript, but in your ASPX file. As far as I know Javascript will not give you a stack overflow, but just makes your browser crash in case of an infinite loop. Try debugging your ASPX page, I really don't think your javascript has anything to do with it!

Comment: It is not going infinite loop as a changed the windos.open with alert and that is working fine here.

Comment: provide more details. Also try opening the page without javascript, do you still get the overflow error, I really doubt that your javascript has to do with it! Also check multiple browsers if you still expect it to be a Javascript error. As far as I know a bug in the window.open is highly unlikely!

Answer (score 0):

Basically: You have a function that (directly or indirectly) calls itself, until it nests too deep and the browser kills your javascript to stop it getting worse.

Comment: I tried with replacing the Winow.open with alert and it is working fine. So may be it is not going recursive kind og a thing.

Comment: @Nits, in that case I am sure it will not be your javascript, but your ASP.NET code. Can you show a screenshot or something?